# How to define a generic array type in React hooks-Typescript?

Tags: typescript, react-hooks, typescript-generics

Hook:

```
const t = Array<number>
const [list, setList]: [t, ListFunction<t> ] = useState(null)
```

Type:

```
export type ListFunction<r> = Array<r[]>
```

Gives:

> Type '[any, Dispatch]' is not assignable to type '[t ListFunction]'.
> Type 'Dispatch' is missing the following properties from type 't[]': pop, push, concat, join, and 27 more.ts(2322)

This works instead:

```
export type ListFunction = Array<any[]>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of `setX` (`setList`) in this case is not `Array<r[]>`. Just set the type of the `useState()` to be `<number[]>`), and let it infer the types of the value, and the set function:

```
const [list, setList] = useState<number[] | null>(null);
```

I would also initialize with an empty array, and avoid the need to check if the value `list` is not `null`.

```
const [list, setList] = useState<number[]>([]);
```

Comment: can you clarify why it's not Array<r[]>?

Comment: Because the `setList` function is a function that accepts an array, and not an Array by itself.

Comment: Array<T> and T[] are two ways of writing the same thing.  Array<T[]> would be an array of arrays of T.